# @Html.Editor showing odd results when using reflected properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, razor

I'm using a generic Razor view to allow any entity framework object to be edited. Here's a cut down version of it:

```
@model Object
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
        @foreach (var property in Model.VisibleProperties())
        {
            @Html.Label(property.Name.ToSeparatedWords())
            @Html.Editor(property.Name, new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
        }
}
```

And the VisibleProperties() function goes like this:

```
public static PropertyInfo[] VisibleProperties(this Object model)
        {
            return model.GetType().GetProperties().Where(info => 
                (info.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || info.PropertyType.Name == "String") &&
                info.Name != model.IdentifierPropertyName()).OrderedByDisplayAttr().ToArray();
        }
```

(I'm reusing code from https://github.com/erichexter/twitter.bootstrap.mvc/)

One of my sample controllers goes as follows:

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            TaskTemplate tasktemplate = db.TaskTemplates.Single(t => t.TaskTemplateID == id);
            return View(tasktemplate);
        }
```

Now the problem:
It all works fine except for where there's  an ID property that relates to a 'parent' table, such as UserID. For these fields, the output of the @Html.Editor is simply:
FalseFalseFalseTrueFalse.

The True seems to correspond to the user in question - in this case the 4th user in the database.

Why is it not ouputting a nice textbox with the number 4 (or whatever the UserID) is in it?

I hope I've explained this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is because editor/display templates are not recursing into complex child objects. If you want this to happen you could write a custom editor template for the object type (`~/Views/Shared/Object.cshtml`) as illustrated by Brad Wilson in [`this blog post`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) (more specifically the `Shallow Dive vs. Deep Dive` section towards the end).

So:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) 
{
    if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) 
    {
        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
    }
    else 
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-label" style="text-align: right;">
                    @(prop.IsRequired ? "*" : "")
                    @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
                    @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. I still don't quite get why it doesn't just show the FirmID as an editable integer value? After all, that's what the property is isn't it? Oddly, I also have an Index controller and view which uses an IEnumerable to display all the properties. In this case, it works fine and presents the integer value perfectly.

Comment: As explained in my answer by default the `Html.Editor` helper does not recurse into complex subproperties. You will have to write a custom editor template for the Object type if you want that to happen.

Comment: Sorry - still don't get it! FirmID is just an `int` in the database. Maybe the question is: how do I stop MVC treating it like some complex value when I just want to get the `int` out? Is there anything I can do using LINQ or the dbcontext to stop this from happening? I know it's possible because of my other code which uses an `Enumerable` list of objects. In this scenario, the `int` is returned properly.